# An indexable Partial

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

How to make `Partial<T>` indexable?

```
let entity: Partial<T> = {};
entity[id] = 444;
```

This is the typescript error:

> No index signature with a parameter of type of 'string' was found on type `Partial<T>`.

Comment: That's the opposite of the point of `Partial<T>`, which is to restrict properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better served by type asserting `id` to be a `keyof T`. Adding an index signature, while possible, will in effect mostly turn off type checking for the variable

```
declare let id: string;
let entity: Partial<T> = {};
entity[id as keyof T] = 444;
```

The assumption here is that `id` is a string representing the key of the type you are indexing. You should probably perform checks beforehand that `id` is indeed a valid key.

```
type T = {
    id: number,
    no: number
}

let id: keyof T = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "id" : "no";
let entity: Partial<T> = {};
entity[id] = 444;
```

If `id` is always a constant, you would do better to just declare `id` as `keyof T`:

For completeness, adding the index signature could be done with an intersection:

```
let entity: Partial<T> & Record<string, T[keyof T]> = {};
entity[id] = 444;
```

Comment: If the variable is named `id`, it probably isn't `keyof T`.

Comment: My assumption is that `id` is a string variable that is expected to contain a key of `T`. The syntax above will satisfy the compiler to allow the access. I will edit to make this more clear.